# pack('C4", $digits) in perl

Tags: perl, cgi

In Writing CGI Applications with Perl, have following code to log visitors.

```
(my $digits = #ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}) =~ s/\.//g;
my $address = pack("C4", $digits);
```

in perldoc,

> pack TEMPLATE,LIST

"C4" should be the template. What's the actual meaning of this?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that that isn’t going to do what I think it is wanting to do.  You’re asking for four things, but `$digits` will contain just one.  You would split on a literal `\.` etc, but the `Socket::inet_aton` solution provided below is better.

Comment: Check the code again.  What you have won't compile.  Even after you fix that issue, I am sure it doesn't match the book.  Based on the many positive reviews that book got, I'd be very surprised if Meltzer and Michalski would advocate changing the value of `$ENV{REMOTE_ADDRESS}`.

Comment: He's not changing the environment variable. The idea is to copy the value into $digits and *modify the copy*. Which doesn't mean that the whole code snippet is not nonsense, because I think it is.

Comment: To the OP: can you point out [where in the book](http://perlcgi-book.com/source.html) you found that code? Because I have a strong feeling you messed something up.

Comment: In page 61. Even correct #ENV to $ENV, this code does not create record in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) docs you mention. The template for C is:

```
C  An unsigned char (octet) value.
```

So  `C4` is four unsigned chars.

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks like a mangled extract from code to convert IP addresses in dotted-quad format to a string of four bytes that can be passed to a `socket` call, for instance.

Assuming that `#ENV` is a mistake for `$ENV`, your code strips out the dots from the dotted quad, giving you a string of 4 to 12 digits. It then (implicitly) interprets those digits as a single integer, putting its least significant 8 bits in the first byte of the result and filling the rest with zeroes (because `pack` supplies empty values for the three missing list elements, which are then interpreted as zeroes).

Why you would want to print a binary IP address to a log file, I won't attempt to guess. But the code as given is close to nonsense. If you do need a binary IP address for something, I recommend

```
use Socket 'inet_aton';
my $address = inet_aton($ENV{REMOTE_ADDR});
```

Comment: my $host = gethostbyaddr($address, AF_INET); It logs the original address, if this code work.

Comment: @Weiyan Excellent. `inet_aton` was more or less designed for that use.